# Why is there a "deep copy" when appending this HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, append

I have a "canvas" element of sorts where its contents are constantly changing.

What I'm trying to do is run a function on every change that captures the contents at that moment and appends it into another element. Like a history of every change.

```
window.updateHistory = function() {
    var snapShot = $('#canv').html();

    $('#history').append('<div>' + snapShot + '</div>');
}
```

Every time the function is called, every element in `#history` updates with the latest iteration.

I can't observe why, `.append` and `.html` both seem to create shallow copies.

Comment: have any plunker for this , or live url ?

Comment: It's a bit cumbersome because of all the code that binds keypresses to editing the HTML, but yeah I'll post it in a bit if no one can immediately recognize the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the clone method. It performs the deep copy of the element.

`window.updateHistory = function() {
    var snapShot = $('#canv').clone().html();
    $('#history').append('<div>' + snapShot + '</div>');
}`

Comment: I want a shallow copy, though. I can't figure out why the code I posted is automatically updating.